# PHP CURL corrupting GZIP file during server-to-server transfer

Tags: php, curl, gzip

One of the open source apps I manage (phpMySQLAutoBackup) uses PHP gzencode to compress the exported SQL data.  It has the option to transfer the compressed file via PHP CURL to a remote server, but the remote copy of the gzencoded file gets corrupted.

Expanding the gz file saved LOCALLY is NOT corrupted.  However, when checking the remote copy it has been corrupted after/during transfer.  Tried PHP CURL, and PHP ftp_fput both corrupt the file, but ONLY when the data is encoded!  Leave OUT the PHP gzencode (so transferring plain text) and the data is transferred without error.

So how do I preserve the data during transfer from server-to-server of the gzencoded data?

BTW: also already tried BINARY mode in both PHP CURL, and PHP ftp_fput.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is "corrupted"? The .gz won't decompress at all? A few bytes in the middle are different? File's longer? shorter?

Have you looked at the resulting corrupted file in a text/hex editor? Maybe there's some PHP warnings getting embedded in the data.

Comment: Hi Marc,  thanks for your response.

It does compress - the original data is of approx size:  900kb, and when gzencoded is 120kb.

CORRUPTED - Sorry, in this context "corrupted" is when the gz file is opened and an extract is attempted these error messages are shown:
"Error: unexpected end of file encountered."
then
"Error:  invalid compressed data to inflate."

and it fails to extract any data.

Comment: Found the issue.  It is not PHP that is the problem.  It was my FTP client!

Each time I downloaded a copy of the gz file it downloaded it in ASCII mode instead of BINARY mode (I normally have it set to binary by default for all sites, but I must have missed this one and it just happened to be the site where all the gz files were).

Oh well, there is a day wasted!

So if you get this error downloading a zip file:

"Error: unexpected end of file encountered."

and

"Error:  invalid compressed data to inflate."

CHECK YOUR FTP client setup so the transfer mode is:  BINARY.